# How to get ZIP code of any location by providing the City name or State name in googlemap using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am willing to get the ZIP code of a location by providing only the City name or State name
in google map using JavaScript.

Is it possible to get the ZIP Code only?

Please let me know.

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

no, that's not enough data to determine a zip code, the query would yield a large block or group of codes (if you could do it at all).

Answer (score 0):

Rajeev, it is not possible to determine the zip code/post code by mentioning only the city name for each city may comprise of tens of hundreds of zip codes based on it's size. However the converse is possible, i.e. obtaining the address, city and state name from a zip code provided by you.